# Create logistic regression with Response as dependent variable and Intercept and Treatment as independent variables

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a logistic regression model with Response (responder / non-responder binomial variable, where response is an event) as dependent variable and Intercept and Treatment as independent variables.
Example dataset:

```
 gender  TRTPN responseCategory 
  <chr>  <dbl> <chr>                         
1 MALE    2     SD                               
2 FEMALE  1     CR                               
3 MALE    2     PD                               
4 MALE    1     SD                            
5 FEMALE  1     PR                               
6 FEMALE  1     SD
```

What I'm doing is first, converting Treatment to a factor. 
Secondly, run a glm:

```
regression <- glm(responseCategoryfac ~ TRTPNfac, data = resp1, family = "binomial")
summary(regression)
```

the output is:

```
Call:
glm(formula = responseCategoryfac ~ TRTPNfac, family = "binomial", 
    data = resp1)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-3.3675   0.0831   0.0831   0.1661   0.1661  

Coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)   4.2767     0.5035   8.495   <2e-16 ***
TRTPNfac2     1.3898     1.1211   1.240    0.215
```

Could you please tell me why the TRTPNfac1 is included in Intercept?
What I'm doing is correctly or not?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1):

Well I can't reproduce your data and it appears you're making both `TRTPN` and `responseCategory` factors but if you're asking the question of whether you can simply suppress the intercept please see below...

```r
gender <- c("Male", "Female", "Male", "Male", "Female", "Female")
TRTPN <- c(2,1,2,1,1,1)
responseCategory <- c("SD", "CR", "PD", "SD", "PR", "SD")
resp1 <- data.frame(gender, TRTPN, responseCategory)
resp1$TRTPNfac <- factor(resp1$TRTPN)
resp1$responseCategoryfac <- factor(resp1$responseCategory)
resp1
#>   gender TRTPN responseCategory TRTPNfac responseCategoryfac
#> 1   Male     2               SD        2                  SD
#> 2 Female     1               CR        1                  CR
#> 3   Male     2               PD        2                  PD
#> 4   Male     1               SD        1                  SD
#> 5 Female     1               PR        1                  PR
#> 6 Female     1               SD        1                  SD
summary(glm(responseCategoryfac ~ TRTPNfac, data = resp1, family = "binomial"))
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = responseCategoryfac ~ TRTPNfac, family = "binomial", 
#>     data = resp1)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>        1         2         3         4         5         6  
#>  0.00008  -1.66511   0.00008   0.75853   0.75853   0.75853  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>             Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> (Intercept)    1.099      1.155   0.951    0.341
#> TRTPNfac2     18.467   7604.236   0.002    0.998
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 5.4067  on 5  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 4.4987  on 4  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 8.4987
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
summary(glm(responseCategoryfac ~ -1 + TRTPNfac, data = resp1, family = "binomial"))
#> 
#> Call:
#> glm(formula = responseCategoryfac ~ -1 + TRTPNfac, family = "binomial", 
#>     data = resp1)
#> 
#> Deviance Residuals: 
#>        1         2         3         4         5         6  
#>  0.00008  -1.66511   0.00008   0.75853   0.75853   0.75853  
#> 
#> Coefficients:
#>           Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)
#> TRTPNfac1    1.099      1.155   0.951    0.341
#> TRTPNfac2   19.566   7604.235   0.003    0.998
#> 
#> (Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)
#> 
#>     Null deviance: 8.3178  on 6  degrees of freedom
#> Residual deviance: 4.4987  on 4  degrees of freedom
#> AIC: 8.4987
#> 
#> Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 18
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! Do you think it not necessary to make both `TRTPN` and `responseCategory` factors? No I do not need to suppress Intercept, it should be included in the model.